# How to write a a script that will reply a message to the screen every time a user aside from root tries to use the wall command?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that would run if a nroot user would use the wall command. Do I write a bash script? If I'll write a wrapper shell script, how would I write the script that would inspect the user id and refuse to call the actual wall command unless the ID matches root?

I am doing this on an AWS instance. In the past, I've tried to use wall by putting some messages but that really didn't replace the wall command. It was just broadcasted to nroot users.

```
#!/bin/bash

wall <<< "You shall not scream"
```

Like I mentioned, when this didn't work I just completely got rid of the other users' access to wall (shown below)

```
chmod g-s /usr/bin/wall
```

Comment: A mild way would be to put it in /sbin or /usr/sbin, places which contain commands usually used by root. Nothing keeps ordinary users from putting these directories in their paths or calling wall with an absolute path, so it's a mild measure, but will probably prevent most accidental uses. A more thorough approach would be to write a wrapper shell script with the name "wall" which resides in e.g. /usr/bin. It would inspect the user id and refuse to call the actual `wall`  command (which would be renamed) unless the ID matches root. Or let root own `wall` and give it 444 permissions.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider How would a wrapper script prevent users from running the wrapped command?

Comment: @hek2mgl It wouldn't, in absolute terms, except that the wrapped command has a funny name and perhaps is in a funny location and perhaps has 700 rights, owned by root. The only advantage to making `wall` proper un-executable right away (or renaming it, or putting it outside standard paths)  is that you can provide a diagnostic output.

Comment: `chmod g-s /usr/bin/wall`, as suggested by the OP, should work

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, how would you write the script that would inspect the user id and refuse to call the actual wall command (which would be renamed) unless the ID matches root?

Comment: Something along the lines of `if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; then <renamed wall> "$@"; else echo "Sorry, wall is only available to root" >&2; fi" >&2; fi`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, last question. when you say renaming wall, did you mean alias? How would you rename it in a shell script?

Comment: No, I mean log in as root and `mv /usr/bin/wall /usr/bin/realwall` or whatever (the path your call in the wrapper script when you invoke the real wall); then, supposing that you tested the wrapper functionality with a script "wall-wrapper.sh" in normaluser's home directory, as root  do `cp ~normaluser/wall-wrapper.sh /usr/bin/wall && chown root /usr/bin/wall` or the like.